# How do I find the URL of a Twitter user WWW page, having only their twitterID?

Tags: api, twitter

Been looking for some time now. Are URLs that directly use userIDs in some way prohibited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a HTTP GET request to http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?user_id=12345 and use the "url" node if you want the URL that users set in their profiles or use "screen_name" node to get the Twitter username.

Check Twitter API documentation about /users/show method

Comment: yes I know, but I was looking for something that could be used directly sans an API, maybe not made it clear in the first place, anyhow marking your answer as the correct one.